# map marker isn't removing. Google Maps Android Maps API V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

So every time the button is pressed everything works fine except the marker does not go away even when the Activity resumes. You would have to restart the Activity or the app, then the marker would go away.

```
public void dismissClicked(View view){

    try {
        //some client code

        if(obj != null && obj.getTitle().equals("lastMarker")){
            obj.remove();
        }

        //loadTask();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you add the marker? If you debug, is the `obj.remove();` line being hit?

Comment: maybe call invalidate() or something that tells the map to redraw its markers